# Bootstrap modal form validation feedback

Tags: php

I'm breaking my head on how I can give the client (live) feedback on a form validation.
The problem is every time you hit the submit button the modal dissapears 
and you need to click again to see the feedback
(if its an error and or it is send succesfuly).
And at least I don't know how I can give live feedback for example: if the user types not a valid email adres the error shows up next to the email colum and when he corrects it, it changes directly

Thanks for helping me I am still in the learning progress

Here is the code,every thing works only the modal disapears and the feedback is not how I would like to have it.

(the language is dutch by the way)

```
<?php

$to = 'thygostriker@gmail.com';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = <<<EMAIL
onderwerp: $subject

Hallo mijn naam is $name

Bricht:$message


EMAIL;

$header = 'Van het e-mail adres $mail';



if($_POST){
    if($name == '' || $email == '' || $message == '' $subject = ''){
     $feedback ='Vul a.u.b. alle velden in'

    }else{
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
         $feedback = 'Uw e-mail is succesvol verzonden';
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a lot of pertinent code.

Comment: Where do I miss pertinent code and what do I need to change? And what is pertinent code

Comment: You didn't post any HTML